# my c# code throws an exception on accessing sql server

Tags: c#, sql-server

i am new to c# and sql
I am creating a simple student database
I added my database created in sql server 2008.
now i have a form where the inputs are given and i have a button insert to insert the data into the database.
But when i click the button i get an exception.

this is my App.config file

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <configuration>
 <startup> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />

 </startup>
 <configSections>
 <connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
  <add name="ConString" connectionString="Data Source=ARAVIND-HP\SQLEXPRESS;            Initial Catalog=test;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.sqlClient"/>
  </appSettings>
    </connectionStrings>
```

`

The form i used is given below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
 using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

 namespace test
 {
   public partial class frmNewStudent : Form
  {

    public frmNewStudent()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void frmNewStudent_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
 private void btnInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         DB_Access access = new DB_Access();
        access.add_student(txtRegNo.Text,txtFName.Text,txtLName.Text,txtPhone.Text);
        MessageBox.Show("Data added successfully");
    }
  }
 }
```

now i have two classes 1.DB_access 2.DB_Connections

the code of DB_access is below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

  namespace test
  {
     class DB_Access
    {
    public SqlConnection conn;
    public DB_Access()
    {   
        conn = DB_Connection.GetConnection();
    }

    public void add_student(string regno, string fname, string lname, string phone)
    { 
        if(conn.State.ToString()=="Closed")
        {
            conn.Open();
        }
       SqlCommand newCmd = conn.CreateCommand();
        newCmd.Connection = conn;
        newCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        newCmd.CommandText = "insert into student values('"+ regno +"','"+ fname   +"','"+ lname +"','"+ phone +"')";
        newCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
   }
  }
```

the code of DB_Connections is below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

 namespace test
 {
    class DB_Connection
    {
    public static SqlConnection NewCon;

    public static string ConStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConString"].ConnectionString;

    public static SqlConnection GetConnection()
    {
        NewCon = new SqlConnection(ConStr);
        return NewCon;
    }


   }
  }
```

when i run this and when i click the insert button i get the following exception:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in test.exe

Additional information: The type initializer for 'test.DB_Connection' threw an exception.

and the line 'conn = DB_Connection.GetConnection();' gets highlighted

i am not able to find the error.please help me with this

Comment: `conn.State.ToString()=="Closed"`??? Yuck!! Use `conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed`...

Comment: but this is not solving the problem

Comment: No, this doesn't solve the problem - that's why I wrote a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the `<appSettings>` node, that part should be just:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="ConString" connectionString="Data Source=ARAVIND-HP\SQLEXPRESS;            Initial Catalog=test;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.sqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

You will get that `TypeInitializationException` when the static fields of the class can't be initialized (maybe because of an exception). That `ConnectionStrings["ConString"]` will result in a `null`, so reading the `.ConnectionString` property gives a NullReferenceException.

Comment: i removed the <appsettings> node but i still get the same exception

Comment: @user1960527 - see the link in the answer by Alexander - you also don't need the `<configSections>` around the `<connectionStrings>`. Try (just for test) placing that `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConString"]` in another part of the code where you can inspect it with the debugger.

Comment: removing <configSections> solved the problem.Thanks for the help everyone

Answer (score 1):

`System.TypeInitializationException` means that program was unable to create type DB_Connection, more precisely was unable to initialize static field `ConStr`.

There is incorrect using of `connectionStrings` section. Look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that problem arises because the `ConStr` static member can not be initialized. Are you able to access the connection string through the configuration manager at other positions in your code just for testing purposes?

Additional tip for what Hans Kesting said: Do not edit the `app.config` file manually unless you have to. You can very easily manage connection strings and other settings using Visual Studio - this also avoids errors.

Comment: yes i understand that the problem is with the initialisation of ConStr.But how to rectify it?

Comment: Use Visual Studio's built in management of the `app.config` to manage connection strings to build a correctly formatted section in the config file. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The `connectionStrings` setting in the web.config has a wrong format.

If fails on this line

```
public static string ConStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConString"].ConnectionString;
```

The content of the `web.config` should be

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="ConString" connectionString="Data Source=ARAVIND-HP\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=test;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.sqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem with connection is in your App.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>  <configuration>  <startup> 
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />

</startup>

<configSections>  <connectionStrings>   <appSettings>   <add
name="ConString" connectionString="Data Source=ARAVIND-HP\SQLEXPRESS; 
Initial Catalog=test;Integrated Security=True"
providerName="System.Data.sqlClient"/>   </appSettings>
</connectionStrings>
```

You don't need tag configSections inside  configuration. Delete it and below startup in configuration paste correct connectionstring. As Alexander said, look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494.aspx and try in this way:

```
"<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<startup>
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
</startup>


<connectionStrings>
  <clear />
  <add name="ConString"
      connectionString="Data Source=ARAVIND-HP\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=test; Integrated Security=True" 
      providerName="System.Data.sqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>


</configuration>"`
```

IMHO that should be ok